# Match different subpath in SSH config

Tags: ssh, configuration

I need to set a configuration for SSH keys related to the same domain but different subpath.
I'd like to have something like:

```
Host                domain.com/sub1
    Hostname        domain.com/sub1
    User            user1
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/key1

Host                domain.com/sub2
    Hostname        domain.com/sub2
    User            user2
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/key2
```

so that when I do `git clone domain.com/sub1...` it uses `~/.ssh/key1` while when doing `git clone domain.com/sub2...` it uses `~/.ssh/key2`.

How can I do that without changing the git repositories' configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSH does not have a concept of "subpath" (as it cares only about server access), so you cannot configure it the way you want. You can use a `Match` entry, which matches the remote host and the remote user, but you cannot match any path element, as SSH cannot have knowledge about what you *will* access once the connection is established.

A `Match` entry matching hosts and users is something like this:

```
Match user="user1" host="domain.com"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1

Match user="user2" host="domain.com"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
```

It practically works the way your config does, but "user2" on "domain.com" will use "key2" regardless of the repository you try to access.